# Matplotlib version is incorrect in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, macports

Python is saying that it is using `matplotlib` version 1.1.1, even though I have version 1.3.1 installed.

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> mpl.__version__
'1.1.1'
```

- Mac OS X
- Python 2.7
- MacPorts installed

When I install py27-matplotlib (1.3.1) using MacPorts, python reports it as being version 1.1.1. When I remove the MacPorts installed module using `sudo port uninstall py27-matplotlib`, python still reports it as using version 1.1.1.

Where is this version coming from and how do I get python to use the newer module instead?

**Update**
sys.path output is as follows:

```
'',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'
```

Comment: Ensured the /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ was in my paths variables (in /etc/paths.d/) but it still reports version 1.1.1

Comment: See `mpl.__file__` to get the path of the module being actually used. Try to move that module to another location (somewhere not in python path).

Comment: Ok, it's using `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/__init__.pyc`. How do I get it to use the one in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/` instead?

Comment: Figured it out. This ended up being a Mac python vs MacPorts python. After a change to my PATH variables to use the MacPorts version first, all is working well.

Comment: @Carl could you please explain more on how you did this? I'm relatively new to python on macs.

Comment: @alavin89, from memory I just added the correct path. Something like this might help ... http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/